# Write in File Error C++

Tags: c++, file

I am facing a problem I cannot solve.
The following code works in most of the cases, but when the number of items that need to be written exceed a number (let's say... 60.000) the file gets written as in the screenshot.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

```
FILE *myfile;
myfile = fopen("ErrorId.txt", "w");
double max_error=0.0005;
for (int i=0; i<(*bodies).size(); i++)
{
    if ((*bodies)[i].material_type>0)
    {
        //if (res_error(i,0)>envi.et*max_error)
        if ((*dofs)[(*bodies)[i].ibody].VEC[0]>max_error)
        //if (res_error(i,0)>envi.et*total_cap)
        {

            std::cout<<env->global_element_id[(*bodies)[i].ibody]<<" ";
            fprintf(myfile, "%d ", env->global_element_id[(*bodies)[i].ibody]);

        }
    }
}
fclose(myfile);
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTI7L.png)

Comment: It seems, that trouble is in the text viewer software: too many chars in single line.

Comment: Try displaying it in a terminal using `cat`. Or using a hex-editor.

Comment: On an unrelated note, I suggest you learn [the C++ I/O library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) and how to use file streams. And probably how to pass things like vectors by *reference* instead of using pointers (generally try to minimize your use of pointers as much as possible, pointers to vectors or other containers are usually not needed).

Comment: Have you heard of `->`? Use `bodies->size()`.

Comment: Thank you all! The editor was indeed the problem!